# How to print series HTML from CSV using filter by similar data?

Tags: php, html, csv

I have a file CSV.
Source = https://bundlespace.com/graphics/example.csv

Data in CSV (example):

```
Image Source,Category Name,Category HTML,Comma Keywords
/data/catalog/premium-graphics/abstract-flowers/watermark/abstract-flower-bud.png,abstract flowers,abstract-flowers.html,"abstract, flower, bud"
/data/catalog/premium-graphics/abstract-flowers/watermark/flower-bud-natural-plant.png,abstract flowers,abstract-flowers.html,"flower, bud, natural, plant"
```

For each category of images I needs to publish series of HTML pages, where includes images for this category. I had a script to convert CSV to HTML and some details for output filtered data (images in listing ). But it needs edit to correct interpretation on server.

```
    <?php
function CSVtoHTML() {
    $row = 0;
    $header = [];
    if (($handle = fopen("fullimagebase.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 2565, ",")) !== FALSE) {

            // first line is header, grab it then continue
            if ( $row === 0) {
                $header = $data;
                $row++;
                continue;
            }
            
            $data = array_combine($header, $data);
            $category = $data['Category Name'];
            
            if (strpos($category == $category++) !== FALSE) {
                $item = '<li><img src="'.Image Source.'" width="200" height="200"></li>';
                echo htmlentities($item);
                echo $item;
                $rows++;
                $items = $item++;
            }           
            return $items;
            
            $content = '<!doctype html>
            <html lang="en">
                <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8">
                    <title>Images in category '.$data['Category Name'].'</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h1 id="graphics">Images in category '.$data['Category Name'].'</h1>                                    
                    <ul>                        
                        '.$items.'
                    </ul>
                </body>
                <footer>FOOTER</footer>
                </html>';

            // make the file
            $filedata = file_get_contents($content);
            $filedata = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8');
            file_put_contents(''.$data['Category HTML'], $filedata);

            $row++;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
CSVtoHTML();
?>
```

In result HTTP ERROR 500 > where is mistake in code of PHP?

Comment: `<?php` inside `<?php` tag.

Comment: @u_mulder how to insert $items in $content="<tags> ... $items ... </tags"?

Comment: Do you know what `return` does? Why you use `return` in the middle of the function code?

Comment: @u_mulder I try to return chosen by if (strpos($category == $category++) !== FALSE) data to use in listing <ul>.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Hello! Your opinion?